# When is it acceptable to call db.SaveChanges() twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller when I am getting a users credentials from AD and saving it into a `Profiles` table. I also want to set some user preferences, however, in order to do this I need the `Id` from `Profile` I just saved to place it in the `Preference` table.

```
var Profile = new Profile
{
    //Id is auto increment
    EmpId = viewmodel.EmployeeId;
    //....
};
db.Profiles.Add(Profile);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Preferences Save:

```
var user = User.Identity.Name;
var getUser = (from gu in db.Profiles where user == gu.EmployeeId select gu.Id).Single();
var Preference = new Preference
{
    UserId = getUser,
    //...
};
db.Preferences.Add(Preference);
db.SaveChanges();
```

In this case, is this acceptable?

Comment: Yes, why not. But you can also assign profile to navigation property (`new Preference { User = profileWhichIsNotYetSaved}`) and call it only once.

Comment: where is uc defined here

Comment: Is it acceptable at any moment where you are not doing batch operations nor transactions

Comment: @Evk Then how does it look it up, what if you have 100 people at one time logging in? Your suggesting I do `UserId = Profile.Id` ?

Comment: ROFL... no i didnt suggest that?? i asked where you define uc.

Comment: `uc` was a typo, I fixed it. I also apologize as I pinged you mistakenly instead of Evk

Comment: @Skullomania you usually have related navigation properties. If UserId is foreign key to Profile table, you have Preference.User property or something, don't you? I suggest to set this property, not UserId. Then when saving changes EF will construct a query for you (of course first profile will be inserted and then preference, but you don't need to care about, plus no need to perform additional database call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your variable `getUser` (please rename this variable) ends up as the newly saved profile Id.. although you havent shown us where you define `uc`.

anyway let me show you the magic of entity framework.

```
var profile = new Profile
{
    //Id is auto increment
    EmpId = viewmodel.EmployeeId;
    //....
};
var preference = new Preference
{
    //...
};

profile.Preferences.Add(preference;)
db.Profiles.Add(profile);
db.SaveChanges();
```

So as you can see you used more than 1 SaveChanges unnecessarily. There are times that you need to have more than one SaveChanges. like lets say you SaveChanges, post an id to an api, retrieve some values and save changes again. I never had to do that actually but i have had times that I need more than 1 save changes. For example I had to copy x amount of database records including x amount of related records into new records in a loop.

Comment: `uc` was a typo I fixed it

Comment: I got a null reference on preference.userId. Not that I understand all that well since it worked well at first.

Comment: okay so it seems that your data relationship is like this? Profiles --->Users<---Preferences

Comment: yes, when a user logs in for the first time the application grabs the user info via Active Directory and saves it into the `Profile` table as a row that same  Id is `UserId` in the `Preference` table.

Comment: wait.. is the primary key of profile table called userid?

Comment: The Preference table has no primary key of its own. it is simply a lookup table with foreign keys pointing to other tables

Comment: that is not the question that i asked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159307/discussion-between-skullomania-and-harry).